# probability distribution estimation from correlated samples

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, estimation

I am looking to solve the following estimation problem. Consider a blackbox where (given below) given an scalar input $X \in \mathcal{X}$, its $N$ observations, $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n \in \mathcal X$ are recorded as output. Here, $\mathcal{X} \equiv \{1, 2, \cdots, M\}$, i.e. $X$ and $Y_i ~\forall i$ can take on $M$ possible values.

The observations are identically distributed, i.e. $Y_i \sim \mathcal{P}(Y|X) $. However, they are not independent.

I would like to know, how can I estimate $\mathcal{P}(Y|X)$ given these N observations. An exemplary solution for binary symbols would be great (i.e. $X,Y_i \in \{0,1\} \forall i$).

Consider again the problem when $X,Y \in \{0,1\}$. In this case $\mathcal{P}(Y|X)$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. I would like to estimate $\mathcal{P}(Y|X)$ with some linear constraints on its components. Therefore, some kind of parametric estimator is preferred.

```
                X
                |
-----------------------------------
|                                 | 
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
  |      |     |      |        | 
 Y_1    Y_2   Y_3    Y_4      Y_N
```

Here is an example for IID observations. Assume $N = 4, X = 0$ and generate $(Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_4)$. Assume we have 100 such observations of $(Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_4)$. The ML estimate of $p_0 = \mathcal{P}(Y=0|X=0) = n_0/400$ where $n_0$ indicates number of observations that were 0. In my case the observations  $(Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_4)$ are identically distributed but not independent.

Comment: I really don't follow your situation. What is X here, a vector? Is it always the same length? Does the black box just split the vector into elements & eject them individually? Can you provide a concrete example (ie, some simple input & output data) to illustrate what you are thinking of?

Comment: Nope X is a scalar and X can take on values from discrete alphabet set. Each Y_i are merely an observation of X. So For example, X and Y_i (for all i) can take on values 0 and 1, and assume X = 0 then each Y_i can take on value Y_i = 0 with (identical for all i) probability P(Y_i = 0 | X = 0) and Y_i = 1 with P(Y_i = 1 | X = 0). So for example X = 0 is the input and (Y_1, Y_2, Y_3) = (0, 1, 0) could be be a possible output. Note that Y_i are not independent of each other. However, I assume that they have identical distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If both $X$ and $Y$ take values in $\{0,1\}$, you have to estimate two quantities
$$p_1=\mathbb{P}(Y=1|X=1)=1-\mathbb{P}(Y=0|X=1)$$and$$p_0=\mathbb{P}(Y=1|X=0)=1-\mathbb{P}(Y=0|X=0)$$So this reduces to inferring about two Bernoulli parameters in two independent problems.